# My events are not displayed in calendar

Tags: views, datetime

Here I have a problem with Views and Calendar modules.
I created test events with a date field.

I configured a view for Calendar with the date field, but no events are displayed ...

How to?

And if possible, how to remove the link on the month names?

thank you very much
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use event_calendar module.. The calendar module only display calendars value. It is not display any event on it... So we are going for event calendar module. It gives various option for display the events and also provide the event content type..